# How do i URL rewrite using .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need some help rewriting URL using .htaccess my urls looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/testro2/product.php?id=426834&productStore=396
```

And i need have it work with text into it, example:

```
http://www.example.com/testro2/product/{anythinghere}/id=4268334&productStore=369
```

or you can make it look more clear like removing `id=` and `&productStore=` will be great, else i can use with them. example

```
http://www.example.com/testro2/product/{anythinghere}/4268334/396
```

The thing is that i need to have my keyword `anythinghere` in the URL.

Also, i would like to rewrite

```
http://www.example.com/testro2/search.php?q=shoes
```

TO

```
http://www.example.com/testro2/search/shoes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your `/testro2/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testro2/

RewriteRule ^product/.+/(\d+)/(\d+)$ product.php?id=$1&productStore=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ search.php?q=$1 [L]
```